# issue in creating data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new with R. I am trying to read two sets of data in R to further use in support vector machine analysis but I am getting an error which I cannot get over it:

```
> x=read.csv("X_values_training.csv",header=F)
> dim(x)
[1]   66 5400
> y=read.csv("Y_values_training.csv",header=F)
> dim(y)
[1]  1 66
> dat =data.frame(x=x,y=as.factor(y))
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

As you can see above, I am reading 66 observation of 5400 vector each. Data in "y" are either 1 or -1 belong to two classes that I have. Can anyone help me with this error?
Thanks

Comment: This is very confusing. What is your goal here? Do you have 66 or 5,400 different x variables? Do you have 1 y variable with 66 different values? 

How do you want this to end up? It would help if you copied a bit of what your data looks like and what the 'goal' data set looks like.

Comment: Jason, Thanks for your help. I have a classification problem where 66 observations are made with 5400 variables. Therefore, X has 66 rows (number of observation) and 5400 columns (number of variables). y is a vector containing 1 and -1 representing the  two classes. Finally, I want to use x and y to run "svm" classification at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `y` is only one row, it's still a data frame. You can tell because (1) it just came from `read.csv` and (2) because it has a `dim` attribute. You can't call `as.factor` on a whole data frame.

```
m <- mtcars[1,]
dim(m)
# [1]  1 11
data.frame(m = as.factor(m))
# Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
# Have you called 'sort' on a list?
is.atomic(m)
# [1] FALSE
```

Try `unlist`-ing `y` before factoring and creating the new column.

```
data.frame(m = as.factor(unlist(m)))
#          m
# mpg     21
# cyl      6
# disp   160
# hp     110
# drat   3.9
# wt    2.62
# qsec 16.46
# vs       0
# am       1
# gear     4
# carb     4
```

However, since `y` is only one row you might be able to use `scan` instead.  This might also work.

```
y <- scan("Y_values_training.csv", what = character(), sep = ",")
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = as.factor(y))
```

Comment: @seyyedalipourmousavi - You could probably use `scan` to read in `y`.  That way it will be a vector.  In which case your subsequent `data.frame` call would work as you have it.  Something like `scan("Y_values_training.csv", what=character(), sep = ",")`